# helm template output showing values not being resolved

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm new to helm charts and K8s, so forgive me.  I'm working on a project that deploys an application project with several apps as part of it.  The previous dev that put the charts together was using a "find-and-replace" technique to fill in values for things like the image repository, tags, etc.  This is making our CICD pipeline development tricky and not scalable.  I'm trying to update the charts to use variables and values.yml files.  Most of it seems to be working, values are getting passed down to the templates except for one part and I can't figure out why.  Its a large project so I won't copy all the chart files. I'll try to lay out the important parts:

**Folder structure:**

```
helm
  project1
     dev
       charts
          app1
            templates
               *template files
            Chart.yaml
            values.yaml
          app2
            *same subfolders
          app3
            *same subfolders
       Chart.yml
       values.yml
```

***Base Values.yml***

```
artifactory_base_url: company.repo.io/repo_folder
imageversions:
  app1_tag: 6.1.2-alpine-edge
  app2_tag: 8.1.0.0-edge
  app3_tag: 8.1.0.0-alpine-edge
  app4_tag: 10.1.1-alpine-edge
  initcontainer: latest
```

***App Values.yml file***

```
app:
  image: 
    repository: "{{ .Values.artifactory_base_url }}/pingaccess"
    tag: "{{ .Values.pa_tag }}"
```

***deployment.yml template file***

```
containers:
      - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        image: "{{ .Values.app.image }}"
```

I'm running the following helm template command to confirm that I'm getting the proper output for at least the app1 part before actually trying to deploy to the k8s cluster.

`helm template app1 --set date="$EPOCHSECONDS" --set namespace='porject_namespace' --values helm/project1/dev/values.yaml helm/project1/dev/charts/app1`

Most of the resulting yaml looks great, and it looks like the values I have defined in the base values.yml file are getting passed through in other areas like this example:

```
initContainers:
  - name: appinitcontainer
      image: "company.repo.io/repo_folder/initcontainer:latest"
```

But there is one portion that is populated from the deployment.yml template file that is still showing the curly braces for variables

```
containers:
  - name: app1
    image: "map[repository:{{ .Values.image_repo_base_url }}/app1 tag:{{ .Values.app1_tag }}]"
    imagePullPolicy: Always
```

I've tried making variations in all the files mentioned above to remove quotes, use single quotes, etc.  In those attempts I usually get a variation of the following errors:
"error converting yaml to json. did not find expected key"
"error mapping values"

I haven't been able to find a solution.  I'm assuming that the "helm template" command should not contain any braces like that, all variables and values should be resolved.  I'm hoping somebody can provide some tips of things I might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting two issues here.  First, `.Values.app.image` is a map containing the two keys `repository` and `tag`; that's why you get the weird `map[repository:... tag:...]` syntax in the output.  Second, string values in `values.yaml` aren't reinterpreted for Helm template syntax; that's why the `{{ ... }}` markup gets passed through to the output.

This in turn means you need to do two things.  To resolve the map, construct the string from the contents of the dictionary; and to resolve the templating markup inside the string values, use Helm's [`tpl`](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) function.

```yaml
{{- $repository := tpl .Values.app.image.repository . }}
{{- $tag := tpl .Values.app.image.tag . }}
image: "{{ $repository }}:{{ $tag }}"
```

(You may find it useful to separate "repository", "registry" or "image", and "tag" into three separate parts, since probably all of your images are coming from the same repository; that would let you configure the repository in one place and customize the image name per component.  The [`bitnami/postgresql`](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql) chart is one example of this setup.)