# Ingress path template is not rendered

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Output of helm version: `v3.12.0`

How to reproduce it?:

```
cd ~
helm create foo

cd foo

vi values.yaml
```

`values.yaml`:

```yaml
ingress:
  enabled: true
  className: ""
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths:
        - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          path: /{{ .Release.Name }} # Changed!!
```

If I run `helm template bar .` that produces:

```yaml
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "chart-example.local"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /{{ .Release.Name }} # Not rendered!!
```

When the above commands are performed, the path value of the output.yaml is not rendered. I'm curious why this is happening.

Comment: You can't normally use template expressions in the `values.yaml` file.  [helm template output showing values not being resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66160890/helm-template-output-showing-values-not-being-resolved) is one example of this.